# Bounded in probability ($o_{P}$)

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, convergence

In Larry Wasserman's [lecture notes](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/) on $o_{P}$ and $O_{P}$, I am not able to follow the derivation of the following example in [page 9](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture2.pdf).

Consider $m$ coins with probabilities $p_{1}, \ldots ,p_{m}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\max_{j} | \hat p_j - p_{j}| > \epsilon)
& \le \sum_{j=1}^{m} \mathbb{P}(\hat p_{j} - p_{j}) \quad \text{(Union bound)} \\
& \le \sum_{j=1}^{m} 2 e^{-2 n \epsilon^{2}} \quad \text{(Hoeffding's inequality)} \\
& = 2 m e^{-2 n \epsilon^{2}}
\end{align*}

I thought of concluding as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we get $\mathbb{P}(\max_{j} | \hat p_{j} - p_{j}| > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ and thus

$$
\max_{j} | \hat p_{j} - p_{j}| = o_{P} (1)
$$

But the author bounds $m$ in terms of $n$ as follows:

Suppose $m \le e^{n^{\gamma}}$ where $0 \le \gamma \le 1$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\max_{j} | \hat p_{j} - p_{j}| > \epsilon) 
& \le 2 m e^{-2 n \epsilon^{2}} \\
& = 2 \exp(-(2 n \epsilon^{2} - \log m)) \\
& \le 2 \exp(-(2 n \epsilon^{2} - n^{\gamma})) \rightarrow 0 
\end{align*}

Then he concludes
$$
\max_{j} | \hat p_{j} - p_{j}| = o_{P} (1)
$$

- The necessity of bounding $m \le e^{n^{\gamma}}$ is to avoid the cases where $m$ is large. Is my understanding correct?
- What happens if the $m \le e^{n^{\gamma}}$ is not satisfied? Can we prove it is not convergent?

Comment: What is $\hat{p}$?

Comment: @Macro $\hat{p}$ is the estimate of $p$

Comment: Wow, sorry about that. I tried to make a few edits, but the $\LaTeX$ appeared to get seriously confused. I think the tweaks they've made to this recently has introduced some bugs.

Comment: @cardinal No problem.

Comment: Your question (and the handout) misses the connection between $n$ and $m$. Is this the number of iid observations of the $m$ coins? Or the total number of observations? If $m$ is fixed, this shows that the max is a $o_P(1)$, not a $O_P(1)$. If $m$ is not fixed, we need $m$ to increase slowly enough to get $o_P(1)$.

Comment: @Xi'an The number of iid observations of $m$ coins is $n$. Thanks for correcting $O_{P}$ to $o_{P}$.

Comment: Still, there is no precision Larry's handout about $m=m(n)$, which implicitly means it could be anything... And the second part of your question remains open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adjusting the notation of Wasserman's notes a little bit, I presume that the problem may be restated like this.

You have $Y^{(i)}_1,\dots,Y^{(i)}_n$ independent and identically distributed $Ber(p^{(i)})$, for $i=1,\dots,m$.

Define the estimates $\hat{p}^{(i)}_n=(1/n)\sum_{j=1}^n Y^{(i)}_j$, for $i=1,\dots,m$.

Then, using subadditivity and Hoeffding's inequality, we have

$$
  P\left(\max_{1\leq i\leq m} |\hat{p}^{(i)}_n - p^{(i)}| > \epsilon\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^m P\left(|\hat{p}^{(i)}_n - p^{(i)}| > \epsilon\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^m 2 e^{-2n\epsilon^2} = 2 m e^{-2n\epsilon^2} = (*) \, .
$$

Now, if the number of coins $m$ is fixed, it is clear that $(*)\to 0$, as $n\to\infty$, and we have the desired result: $\max_{1\leq i\leq m} |\hat{p}^{(i)}_n - p^{(i)}|=o_P(1)$.

But Wasserman seems to do more and allows $m$ to grow with $n$. In this case, as long as $m\leq e^{n^\gamma}$, for $0\leq\gamma<1$, we have $(*) \leq 2\exp(-(2n\epsilon^2-n^\gamma)) \to 0$, as $n\to\infty$, and we have the same conclusion of the former case.